# Unexpected result when trying to continuously prompt until they give an integer-only input

Tags: c, input, integer, scanf, prompt

Issue: when the user inputs 'q', the prompt (Number: ) will show up again (which is expected). However, when the user inputs, "q q", the prompt will appear twice ie (Number: Number: ). And when the user inputs "q q q", the prompt will appear 3 times ie (Number: Number: Number: ). 
is there anyway to fix this code?
i am new to programming so i would really appreciate it if you try to explain the problem in layman terms.

```
int main(void)
{

    char number[17];
    while (true)
    {
        printf("Number: ");
        scanf("%s", number);
        int i;
        char c;
        if (sscanf(number, "%i %c", &i, &c) == 1)
        {
            printf("%i\n", i);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `scanf`, use `fgets`.

Comment: BTW: what shoukd happen if the user inputs `q q q`, ?

Comment: the prompt (Number: ) should only appear once regardless of how many spaces.

Answer (score 2):

i have edited the code according to what u guys have said and it works. Can someone explain to me why this works?

```
int main(void)
{

    char number[17];
    while (true)
    {
        printf("Number: ");
        fgets(number, 17, stdin);
        int i;
        char c;
        if (sscanf(number, "%i %c", &i, &c) == 1)
        {
            printf("%i\n", i);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW: `fgets(number, 17, stdin);` -> `fgets(number, sizeof(number), stdin);`. That way you specify `17` only at _one_ place.

Comment: i would like to understand y scanf would cause the prompt to appear more than once.

Comment: Number: a bc def g h
scanned a
Number: scanned bc
Number: scanned def
Number: scanned g
Number: scanned h
Number:

Comment: but scanf continues to scan the chars after the space in the next loop. is that due to the buffer still storing the remaining user's input?

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to call `fflush(stdin)` to clear input buffer.

```
 if (sscanf(number, "%i %c", &i, &c) == 1)
    {
        printf("%i\n", i);
        return 0;
    }
 else fflush(stdin);
```

Comment: at which line should i implement it tho.

Comment: as `else` statement

Comment: _fflush(stdin)_: is undefined behaviour. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin